# Подстановка аргументов в запрос nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

Есть `location /test1`. В нём делается запрос, и создаются аргументы вида `&arg_type=new&arg2=200` и т.д.
Для использования в любом location я загоняю эти аргументы в куки.
`add_header Set-Cookie "myargs=&arg_type=new&arg2=200;Max-Age=60";`
И возникли проблемы с использованием в другом location.
Т.е. есть location:

```
location /new {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/new/;
}
```

Если подставить мои аргументы в этот location вида `http://example.com/new/&arg_type=new&arg2=200`, то должно заредиректить на страницу создания карточки, где аргументы раскидаются по полям.
И возникли трудности с реализацией.
Если просто в конце proxy_pass добавить,то в течении 60 секунд будет редиректить только на эту страницу.

Если делать rewrite вида:
`rewrite ^(.*) http://$server_name/$1/$cookie_myargs`, то идёт постоянный редирект на эту страницу,пока кука жива. Пробовал использовать permanent/last/break, но безрезультатно. Либо постоянный редирект, либо аргументы подставляются несколько раз.
Так же пробовал конструкцию вида (проверка наличия тестовой куки,которая создаётся вместе с аргументами). Итог одинаковый. Получается бесконечный цикл,который живёт 60 секунд.

```
if ($cookie_myargscheck ~* (true)){
    rewrite ^(.*) http://$server_name/$1/$cookie_myargs break/last/permanent;
}
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как это правильно реализовать.
Вариант с кукой нужен, т.к. при прохождение авторизации через сервер SSO идёт 2 редиректа. Первый - запрос на авторизацию,а второй после успешной авторизации. При каждом редиректе идёт декодирование ссылки, а т.к. аргументы уже декодированы,то при этом самом декодировании они отбрасываются. Соответственно до точки назначения доходит только `http://example.com/new/`

Comment: Два раза прочитал и так и не понял что происходит и зачем…

Comment: «При каждом редиректе идёт декодирование ссылки,» — мне кажется что ошибка где-то тут. Возможно что-то где-то надо правильно настроить или правильно кодировать

Comment: @AlexeyTen К сожалению,это особенность SSO. Приходится с этим мириться

Comment: Ну так можно закодировать дважды

Comment: @AlexeyTen У меня есть вариант с двойным кодированием вида %2526arg_type%253D$arg_arg_type%2526arg2%253D$arg_arg2 . Вся проблема в том,что это для проекта завязано много сервисов. Т.е фронт передаёт аргументы в /test1 ,там я эти аргументы загоняюю в куку,т.к. там делается rewrite с редиректом в другой сервис. Пока они доходят до моего локейшена,то соответственно запрос уже не такой. 
Мне бы какой-нибудь вариант,который бы при существовании этой куки делал один раз редирект на http://$server_name/$1/$cookie_myarg ,а дальше отрабатывал бы по логике приложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым. После проверки cookie на true внутри цикла сразу меняю её на false,и редирект проходит только один раз,и логика приложения не нарушается

```
if ($cookie_myargscheck ~* (true)){
    add_header Set-Cookie "myargscheck=false;Path=/;Max-Age=60";
    rewrite ^(.*) http://$server_name/new/$cookie_myargs permanent;
}
```